# Complex Analysis - Bruce P. Palka - Ex. 4.18

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Currently I think that I'm stuck on the following problem, and I would like some hints on how to proceed:

> For which complex numbers $z$ is it true that $\sqrt{z/\bar{z}} = z /|z|$?

My work so far: Since $z/|z| = (|z|e^{i\varphi_z})/|z| = e^{i\varphi_z}$, and $\sqrt{z/\bar{z}} = \exp((1/2)\mathrm{Log}(z/\bar{z})) = \exp((1/2)(\ln((|z|^2)/|z|) + i\varphi_{z/\bar{z}})) = \exp((1/2)\ln(|z|) + i(1/2)\varphi_{z/\bar{z}})$, we see that necessarily $|z| = 1$, so that $(1/2)\ln(|z|) = 0$. We need to have that $(1/2)\varphi_{z/\bar{z}} \in (-\pi, \pi]$. This is ensured when $(1/2)\mathrm{Arg}(z/\bar{z}) = (1/2)(\arg(z/\bar{z}) + 2\pi k) = (1/2)(2\arg(z) + 2\pi k) = \arg(z) + \pi k \in (-\pi, \pi]$.

Here's where I am stuck: In what (if any) way can we conclude the equality between $\varphi_z$ and $\varphi_{z/\bar{z}}$ from the argument above? We know that the suitable elements are some elements of the unit circle, but which ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following response arguably defective in that it bypasses your analysis in favor of a shortcut.

Use that $z\overline{z} = |z|^2.$

Therefore

$\displaystyle \sqrt{\frac{z}{\overline{z}}}
= \sqrt{\frac{z \times z}{z \times \overline{z}}}
= \frac{\sqrt{z \times z}}{|z|}.$

Therefore, the question immediately reduces to identifying all complex numbers $z$ such that

$\sqrt{z \times z} = z.$

I am familiar with Palka's book, and his convention that for all complex non-zero $w$, the principal square root of $w$ will have it's real portion non-negative.  This means that instead of the argument of the square root being allowed to be in the half open interval $(-\pi, \pi]$, the argument of the square root is required to be in the half open interval $(-\pi/2, \pi/2].$

This immediately resolves the question, without math.  For non-zero $z$, you will have $\sqrt{z \times z} = z$ if and only if the argument to $z$ is in the half open interval $(-\pi/2, \pi/2].$

---

**Addendum**
Responding to the comment/question of Epsilon Away.

Assume that non-zero $z$ has form $re^{i\theta}$, where $r > 0$ and $-\pi < \theta \leq \pi.$  Then, the equation

$\displaystyle \sqrt{z \times z} = z$

reduces to the equation

$\displaystyle \sqrt{r^2} \times \sqrt{e^{2i\theta}} = re^{i\theta}.$

This reduces to the equation

$\displaystyle \sqrt{e^{2i\theta}} = e^{i\theta}.$

There are two non-zero complex numbers $w$ such that $w^2 = e^{2i\theta}$.  Namely $w_1 = e^{i\theta}$ and $w_2 = e^{i(\theta + \pi)}.$

Per the convention of Palka, the principal square root of $\displaystyle \sqrt{e^{2i\theta}}$ will be designated to be either $w_1$ or $w_2$ depending on which of the two arguments, $\theta$ or $(\theta + \pi)$ happens to lie in the half open interval $(-\pi/2, \pi/2]$ (within a modulus of $2\pi$).

Thus, $\displaystyle \sqrt{e^{2i\theta}}$ will be designated as $w_1$, rather than $w_2$ if and only if $\theta$ lies in the half open interval $(-\pi/2, \pi].$

Comment: Could you elaborate why the argument of the square root needs to be in the half open interval $(-\pi/2, \pi/2]$? I mean that since $\sqrt{z^2} = \exp((1/2)(\ln(|z|^2) + i\mathrm{Arg}(z^2))) = \exp(\ln|z| + i(1/2)\mathrm{Arg}(z^2))$, don't we need that $(1/2)\mathrm{Arg}(z^2) \in (-\pi, \pi] \Longleftrightarrow \mathrm{Arg}(z^2) \in (-2\pi, 2\pi]$? 

Edit: I'm an idiot: From $(1/2)\mathrm{Arg}(z^2) = \mathrm{Arg}(z)$ it follows that $\mathrm{Arg}(z) \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2]$.

Comment: @EpsilonAway See the Addendum to my answer.